# Is it possible to create an instance of a class on the stack?

Tags: c#, heap-memory, new-operator, memory-model, stack-memory

I know that in C++ you can create an instance of a class on the stack like

```
MyClass mc = MyClass(8.2);
```

or on the heap like

```
MyClass * mc = new MyClass(8.2);
```

Can you do the same thing in C#? The only way I ever create a class in C# is by `new`ing it.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/

Comment: It is only semantics, objects still live on the GC heap.  Invented to rescue the RAII pattern.  Largely a failure, terminally confusing programmers about when to use the hat and getting them to write very inefficient code that boxes far too often.

Comment: C# is a managed heap memory model - the whole point is that you don't have to spend time worrying about memory clean up.  Is there a reason you want to put something on the stack vs. the heap?  

FWIW, C# structures (value types) generally are on the stack and classes (reference types) are on the heap - BUT the memory manager may choose to box it based on size and usage.

Comment: @GeoffCox When a value type is boxed is well defined.  It will always box the value when you store it in a storage location of a reference type, and never otherwise.  It doesn't choose when or when not to box a value at its whim.  Now a variable itself may well have a number of possible storage locations, and the storage location of a variable itself *can* change at the whim of the language/runtime, but that's unrelated to boxing.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible.  All instances of all classes are always allocated on the heap.

It is value types, including user defined `struct` types, that hold values, rather than references to values elsewhere, that can store a value in whatever location that variable happens to store its value in, which may not be the heap.

Comment: @Dan They're allocated in some "other location" for storing objects with an unknown lifetime.  The CLR calls that location "the heap".

Comment: I agree with @Dan I remember that the CLR is free for example to create instances that are only used locally (in local variables) on the stack.

Comment: @RenéVogt It's required that the variables be a reference to an object elsewhere, rather than having the variable store the value, and it's required that the referenced storage location be able to live for an indeterminate amount of time (which isn't true of a stack frame).